# How to use three different keys e.g. (Ctrl Shift O) to open a form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to use three different keys e.g, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>) to open another form in vb.net.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the keydown event you can access these keys. For example, in this handler...

```
Private Sub keyDown(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) handles me.keydown
```

...you can use the booleans e.Alt, e.Control, and e.Shift to tell whether those control keys are down. Then you can do something like this:

```
Select case CInt(e.keycode)
  case Keys.F12
    if e.Control andalso e.Shift then frm.ShowDialog
    ...
```

Comment: How to use 3 shortcut key in .net coding

Comment: `And` => `AndAlso`. Make it a habit to **always** use the short-circuited operatons in boolean expressions.

Comment: You're probably right, although I think that should be the optimizer's job. `Andaslo` is great when it matters which side is done first. Orelse is good, too.

Answer (score 1):

Define this [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As IntPtr) As Short
```

So you can check wich keys are pressed at the same moment:

```
'For example, keys "arrow up" and letter "W"
If GetKeyState(87) < 0 AndAlso GetKeyState(38) < 0 Then
     'Do something
End If
```

And you can check the keys in a KeyDown event or with a Timer or anything. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it with key events as in xpda's answer, or, *if you already have a MenuItem* to do the same action, you can set the [ShortcutKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.shortcutkeys.aspx) property of the ToolStripMenuItem.