# Multiple non-modifier key event - VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way of recognizing multiple keypress combinations that **do NOT** include a modifier?

I know the method for detecting and working with `Modifier` + `Normal key` combinations - under the `MyBase.KeyDown` event, `e.KeyCode` provides numbers which relate to each keyboard letter. I know how to combine these, by using `e.Modifier` and *`Keys.`whatever*.

So I want to be able to recognize a multi-key combination such as `C` + `T` - which doesn't include a `Modifier`. Is this possible?

Comment: since e.KeyCode can contain only one value at a time, you'd have to keep track of the previous key to see if it equals "C" OR "T", the of course clear the previous character pressed when it is NOT "C" and NOT "T"

Comment: @Plutonix so I'm guessing there's no proper method like there is when using `Modifier`s? Oh well, just an idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old school way:

```
Public Class Form1

  Dim combination As New List(Of Keys)({Keys.T, Keys.C})
  Dim currentKeys As New List(Of Keys)

  Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    currentKeys.Add(e.KeyCode)
    If currentKeys.Intersect(combination).Count = combination.Count Then
      'this is our combo
      MessageBox.Show("Fatality!")
      currentKeys.Clear()
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    currentKeys.Remove(e.KeyCode)
  End Sub

End Class
```

This will trigger if both C and T are pressed at the same time, but not if they are pressed separately. Also when {C, T} and some other letter was pressed in between (any combination that includes {C, T}). You can modify it to fire only when {C, T} were pressed (so {C, T, X}, for example, would not work). Let me know if you need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, with [`GetKeyState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.getkeystates%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As IntPtr) As Short
```

Then, for example, control each key you want to check if it's pressed:

```
Dim keypressed As Keys 

If GetKeyState(87) < 0 OrElse GetKeyState(38) < 0 Then : keypressed = Keys.Up 
ElseIf GetKeyState(65) < 0 OrElse GetKeyState(37) < 0 Then : keypressed = Keys.Left 
ElseIf GetKeyState(68) < 0 OrElse GetKeyState(39) < 0 Then : keypressed = Keys.Right 
ElseIf GetKeyState(83) < 0 OrElse GetKeyState(40) < 0 Then : keypressed = Keys.Down 
Else : keypressed = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Am I right in assuming that the number in brackets is the actual reference number that is simply prettified by Visual Studio into `Keys.`Whatever? In this case, would you write therefore use 84 as the code for `T` and 67 for `C`, which are the official numbers?

Comment: The number in brackets is a enum provided in `System.Windows.Input.Key`

Comment: I don't seem to be able to access `System.Windows.Input.Key`. I doesn't suggest this - is this a feature not available in .NET 4.0 / Visual Studio 2010 Express? (what I'm running)?

Comment: Checks this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14377813/1967056 (I knew I had answered this before)

Comment: Yes, sorry about not clicking accept on the answer I used. I appreciate the effort of making an answer, but I found Neolisk's answer a little clearer/easier. If you upvote this question I can upvote your answer to show my appreciation.